# Regular expression to validate the mobile number for the following scenario?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular Expression for validating numbers with one space and one optional special character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717990/regular-expression-for-validating-numbers-with-one-space-and-one-optional-specia)

I have to write a regular expression to validate mobile numbers which look like below:

a).Maximum 12 characters

b).Will allow a space (at a non-defined point)

c).Must start with 0

d).Followed by an optional extension number of up to five digits in length, not including the # sign

I have tried with the following to get 0-12 numbers. but i don't know how to add the optional extension numbers part (the # and followed by numbers)

```
^(0(?:\d{0,11}|(?=\d* \d*$)[\d ]{0,12}))$
```

Comment: what you have done so far ?

Comment: There are several answers on validating phone numbers using regexen on SO already. Going through a regex for every possible format of phone number conceivable isn't one of the goals of this site. I am sure you can work this out if you have a look at some of the other answers and go through a few more iterations of trial and error.

Comment: Please don't post the same question twice, edit the first one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717990/regular-expression-for-validating-numbers-with-one-space-and-one-optional-specia

Comment: @user1863261 - I strongly advise against using multiple identities (like the one used to post this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13721153/regular-expression-for-following-scenario - *note only those with mod tools will see this*)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create regular expressions for each format. You can then combine them into a single regular expression using the alternation construct `|`.

The first pattern is the most tricky one but you have provided a way to solve it by using a zero-width positive lookahead assertion yourself (here I assume that the space is only allowed **between** numbers):

```
(?=\d+ \d+#)[\d ]{12}#\d{5}
```

The next pattern is straightforward:

```
\d{11}
```

You definition of the last pattern is a bit vague but doing various assumptions I have selected this pattern:

```
\d{1,12}#\d{1,5}
```

The combined regular expression is then:

```
^(?=\d+ \d+#)[\d ]{12}#\d{5}|\d{11}|\d{1,12}#\d{1,5}$
```

Comment: You don't need 10 patterns for the first part, as OP shows with his own code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex. It will satisfy a,b,c and d conditions

```
(?<=^)([\d\s]{13}|\d{12}|0\d{11}|\d{5})(?=$)
```

Comment: :All i need is follows:Maximum 12 characters,Will allow a space (at a non-defined point), Must start with 0,Followed by an optional extension number of up to five digits in length, not including the # sign

Comment: @user1863261: The requirement you have described in your comment does not match those in your question making it hard to properly answer your question.